# Changing column Datatype from date to datetime without removing existing values in MSSql and Oracle sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table *student* containing a date column *dateModified* which is not nullable. I want to change the column data type to datetime. I tried following sql in the MSSql server:

```
ALTER table student alter column dateModified datetime not null
```

and getting following error:

```
The object '....' is dependent on column 'dateModified'
ALTER TABLE STUDENT ALTER COLUMN DATEMODIFIED DATETIME NOT NULL failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

There is no constraints depending on the column. there is a primary key which is not related to the column.

There are thousands of existing records in the student. I tried running the sql in a empty table and it worked without any errors. Could anyone please tell me how can I alter the table without removing any records from the table? If possible please also provide a sql for Oracle sql. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, Because there is no constraints on the column.

Comment: *Something* is using that column. It may be a foreign key, a constraint or a default. In fact, the error seems to be telling you what is going on already - `The object 'XZYZ' is dependent on column 'dateModified'`. What object is this?

Comment: The error message gives you a specific name - what is that name and what type of object is it?